# set max transaction duration in DB2

Tags: transactions, db2

Is there a way to set a max duration for transactions in DB2 10.1?

My application makes a query that lasts for about 10 minutes on the database. My application though waits only for 240 seconds for an answer, so after that the transaction will time out.
But on my db monitor I see that the query is still running and is using a lot of CPU.
I would like to stop that query also, because my application is not going to see the results anyway (with the current configuration). Is there a way to config DB2 to stop such long running queries?

In my application I run this:

```
List<MyData> result = query.getResultList();
```

And in my SystemOut.log I end up with this:

```
0000000b TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[WebContainer : 305,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
```

The query command though is not interrupted but waits until the db is finished and I get a transaction exception. So the connection is still intact but my transaction was timed out before.
(The application is running on WAS 8.0)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for the query continuing to execute is that, while the connection running it is returned to the pool, it is not closed.

DB2 for LUW includes the Workload Manager feature that allows you to define various thresholds for specific identifiable workloads and perform some actions when the thresholds are exceeded, including stopping the running activity. You will find [examples of how to define a threshold and the associated *work action*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0051985.html) in the manual.

Note that most Workload Manager features require the Advanced Enterprise Edition license for DB2.